# How to make android command print

Tags: php, android, vb.net, web-services

I have a project about point of sales. I want my android to print an invoice for every sales occurred.

I am using Android Studio for Android application. I am using `SQL` server and my application on desktop uses vb.net language (visual studio 2012).

[image: this]

That is my structure.
How can I make android  print invoices using the printer that is connected on my computer? I am making the invoice design on my desktop Application. thanks!

Comment: You could write something to your database from your android app indicating that the invoice should be printed, for example a table called PrintInvoices with a link to the invoiceid or whatever and a status. You could then add something to your desktop application that checks this table every x seconds and prints the invoices that have not been printed yet (based on status field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a web service seems natural to have there a function to print your invoice, just tell the service the invoice id, for example /service/print/invoice/7
I suggest you to return a print job id so you can query it's status from your android  (/service/print/job_id/status) or even cancel it (/service/print/job_id/cancel)

create a pending print job in your database

The tricky thing I assume you want to know is how to communicate your web service with your app, as you are using windows I will recommend you to send the order to you app as a windows message. just find your app window with FindWindowEx (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), if the app is not running, launch it and wait until you can find the window.
Once you have the window handler send a user message to it, user messages are messages with its id over WM_USER (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931(v=vs.85).aspx), for example use WM_USER +1  for checking pending printing jobs.

for sending the message use PostMessage:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> 


Private Shared Function PostMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
```

hWnd is the handle of your app window you have retrieved with FindWindowEx (check that is not null)
Msg y the messageId, in this example should be WM_USER+1
wParam and lParam are integers you can send as parameters check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for more info on PostMessage

in your app just override the WndProc and when you recevie a message check if its a print-invoice message (WM_USER +1--> &H401) and execute pending printing jobs from DB.

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
Select Case m.Msg
    Case &H401
        ExecutePendingPrintingJobsFromDB()
    Case Else
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Select
End Sub
```

You can also define other user messages for other stuff.

hope that helps.